# Laravel, creating schema and models

Tags: php, laravel

I'm learning laravel and struggling with one thing,

what is the use of laravel model class:

```
class User extends Model
```

when still I have to do mapping like this:

```
  public function handle()
{
    $this->createUserTable();
}

private function createUserTable()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('user');
    Schema::create('user', function ($table) {
        $table->increments('user_id');
    });
}
```

and add it to artisan commands etc etc. , for example I need mapping ManyToOne, then should I define it both in Model class , and then in Artisan script? Or is it somehow out of the box??

I mean where is the place to connect both my hand written-sql-like-mapping with User model class

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: I just downloaded it from official page so its 5.3, so says composer.json "laravel/framework": "5.3.*"

Comment: Magic. Firstly, the code you have in your artisan command can actually be put in a migration instead. Have a look at https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/8 and https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/14 These should give you a decent understanding of how to use `Eloquent` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Each database table has a corresponding "Model" which is used to interact with that table. Models allow you to query for data in your tables, as well as insert new records into the table.

The idea behind models (and Eloquent ORM in particular) is to provide an easy-to-use interface for you to interact with data that your application deals with via objects.

Note that you do not have to edit the artisan script. Laravel was designed to work out of the box as much as possible. What you should do is define a migration file and then a corresponding model. You can do these easily and in a single step by running `php artisan make:model User -m create_users_table`. You then edit the generated files to match your schema.

I've found [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#defining-models) to be extremely helpful in getting a better understanding of how Laravel works. I think you would benefit by going through it, too.